# Unable to check user id into mongoose database array and giving error?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, axios

I have a model photos which has likes field and likedBy fields. Storing user id into liked by field and increase the like number based on user. I am not able to check if user already liked the image he should not like it again.

My route is :

```
exports.postLikes = (req, res, next) => {
    const action = req.body.action;
    const counter = action === 'Like' ? 1 : -1;
    if (action == 'Like') {
        PhotoEntries.findById({
            _id: req.params.id
        }, (err, photo) => {

            const alreadyDownvoted = photo.likedBy.includes(req.user.id);
            if (alreadyDownvoted) {
                let _downvoted = photo.likedBy.filter(id => id !== req.user.id);
                photo.likedBy = _downvoted;

                PhotoEntries.update({
                    _id: req.params.id
                }, {
                    $inc: {
                        likes_count: +1
                    },
                    $push: {
                        likedBy: req.user._id
                    },
                    LikeorUnlike: true
                }, (err, photo) => {


                })
            }
        })
    } else {

        PhotoEntries.findById({
            _id: req.params.id
        }, (err, photo) => {

            const alreadyUpvoted = photo.likedBy.includes(req.user.id);

            if (alreadyUpvoted) {
                PhotoEntries.update({
                    _id: req.params.id
                }, {
                    $inc: {
                        likes_count: -1
                    },
                    $pull: {
                        likedBy: req.user._id
                    },
                    LikeorUnlike: false
                }, (err, photo) => {

                })
            }

        })
    }

    res.send('');

}
```

I am able to store user into likedBy field and as well able to increase +1 if user liked it but Unable to verify whether user already liked or not and also not able to store the like button state.

If user like the button it is come to unlike but when I refresh it become like and but like count will saving in data base.

I am using AXIOS :

```
var updatePostStats = {
    Like: function(postId) {
        document.querySelector('#likes-count-' + postId).textContent++;
    },
    Unlike: function(postId) {
        document.querySelector('#likes-count-' + postId).textContent--;
    }
};

var toggleButtonText = {
    Like: function(button) {
        button.textContent = "Unlike";
    },
    Unlike: function(button) {
        button.textContent = "Like";
    }
};

var actOnPost = function(event) {
    var postId = event.target.dataset.postId;
    var action = event.target.textContent.trim();
    toggleButtonText[action](event.target);
    updatePostStats[action](postId);
    axios.post('/' + postId + '/like', {
        action: action
    });
};
```

I have two issues:
One is not able to verify user id in the array of 'likedby' whether is it exist or not and other one after like button become unlike, if i refresh the page it again comes to like.

I am able to update like to unlike basis on user id stored in likedby. How can achieve that?

Comment: I think your first mistake may be here ```const alreadyDownvoted = photo.likedBy.includes(req.user.id)```. Shouldn't it be ```const alreadyDownvoted = photo.likedBy.includes(req.params.user.id)``` or something...```req``` doest not have a parameter ```user```...there seems to be multiple referencing issues

Comment: Even after using params , It is not working

Comment: Any alternative?